# Why is TestUtils.Simulate.click in Jest not working when used directly on React Components?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Let's say I have 2 components. A parent that contains a child.

The child component is a button like so:

```
var React = require('react');

var ChildButton = React.createClass({
  onSubmitAnswer: function(e) {
    this.props.onClick(this);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.visibility}>
          <button onClick={this.onSubmitAnswer}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    )
  }

});

module.exports = ChildButton;
```

It lives within it's parent, which looks like this:

```
var React = require('react'),
    ChildButton = require('./face-submit-button');

var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
  onButtonSubmit: function() {
    //Something happens here
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        //Some more components
        <ChildButton text="Submit" onClick={this.onButtonSubmit} />
      </div>
    )
  }

});

module.exports = ParentComponent;
```

So far so good. Everything works as expected in the UI. But I've encountered some issues in the Jest tests using TestUtils.Simulate.click().

My test for the ChildButton component is straightforward and behaves as I would expect.

```
jest.dontMock('./child-button');

describe('ChildButton', function() {
  var React = require('react/addons'),
      ChildButton = require('./child-button'),
      TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

  describe('events', function() {
    var button,
        onClickStub;

    beforeEach(function() {
      onClickStub = jest.genMockFn();

      button = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <ChildButton onClick={onClickStub} />
      );
    });

    it('should call onSubmitAnswer when the button is clicked', function() {
      var buttonTag = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(button, 'button');

      TestUtils.Simulate.click(buttonTag);

      expect(onClickStub).toBeCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

My test for the parent component started out looking the same:

```
jest.dontMock('./parent-component');

describe('ParentComponent', function() {
  var React = require('react/addons'),
      ParentComponent = require('./parent-component'),
      ChildButton = require('./child-button'),
      TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

  describe('events', function() {
    var parent,
        onClickStub;

    beforeEach(function() {
      onClickStub = jest.genMockFn();

      parent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <ParentComponent onClick={onClickStub} />
      );
    });

    it('should call onButtonSubmit when a click is triggered', function() {
      var childButton = TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(parent, ChildButton);

      TestUtils.Simulate.click(childButton);

      expect(onClickStub).toBeCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

But this test fails. The only difference I can see between these two tests is that one uses an HTML tag directly and clicks on it, while the other triggers a click on a React component. Can I not use the click event on React components directly? Is my assumption correct?

And if so, is there a way to trigger a click on React components differently in the tests? I tried using SimulateNative but that had the same effect, the onClickStub doesn't get called on click.

Comment: Sounds like the simulated click is not bubbling up to the parent.  If you simulate click on parent instead of the button, does it work as expected?

Comment: But I want to test that the click works on the button, not the parent, which can have many different subcomponents. I've tried your suggestion and that fails just the same.

Comment: But Parent's onClick should happen whenever anything in the parent is clicked, not just the childButton.  Not sure what else to try if simulating the click on Parent itself isn't working.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure that assumption is quite correct. I'm trying to test that the onClick event on the button fires and in turn calls the onButtonSubmit function. The way I tested it so far is that I have a stub in that function and I just check that it's called. But using onClick on the button directly or the parent itself doesn't fire the event, hence my assumption that maybe onClick events don't work on React components and there must be another way.

Comment: So, since onClick shouldn't actually happen on any click on Parent, why not do something like <Parent submitFn={stub} /> and change the onButtonSubmit function to call this.props.submitFn().

Answer (score 2):

There is currently an open bug for this issue: [Let ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click work on non-dom components](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1445). So the answer is that due to bugs, you can only use `Simulate.click` on an actual DOM node. So you can workaround the bug by getting the DOM node until it is fixed.